ASV table help, how to convert long string into individual genus and species
Currently each sample has this in a column in a large string. I want to create separate columns for genus and species. Help?
d__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Bacilli; o__Lactobacillales; f__Streptococcaceae; g__Streptococcus
